# Scala/Hadoop: Compiler error when using classOf[CustomInputFormat] unless instance of CustomInputFormat exists

Tags: scala, hadoop

I've defined a custom input and output format over in `XMLIO.scala`:

```
import scala.xml.Node
import org.apache.hadoop.lib.input.FileInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.lib.output.FileOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.{ RecordReader, RecordWriter }
// ...
object XMLIO {
    class XMLInputFormat extends FileInputFormat[LongWritable, Node] { /*...*/ }
    class XMLRecordReader extends RecordReader[LongWritable, Node] { /*...*/ }
    class XMLOutputFormat extends FileOutputFormat[LongWritable, Node] { /*...*/ }
    class XMLRecordWriter extends RecordWriter[LongWritable, Node] { /*...*/ }
}
```

Which I'm trying to use for a job I'm defining over in `Example.scala`:

```
import XMLIO._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
object Example {
    @throws(classOf[Exception])
    def main( args : Array[String] ) {
        val job = new Job(new Configuration(), "")
        job setInputFormatClass classOf[XMLInputFormat]
    }
}
```

However, this is giving me a compiler error:

```
[ERROR] /path/to/Example.scala:8: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : java.lang.Class[XMLInputFormat](classOf[XMLInputFormat])
[INFO]  required: java.lang.Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat]
[INFO]     job setInputFormatClass classOf[XMLInputFormat]
[INFO]                                    ^
```

Which seemed odd to me, given that `XMLInputFormat` is a subclass of `FileInputFormat`, which is a subclass of `InputFormat`.

Playing around a bit in the REPL, I found a weird workaround.  If I create an instance of `XMLInputFormat` before I set the input format class, there's no compiler error.  That is, the following compiles fine:

```
import XMLIO._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
object Example {
    @throws(classOf[Exception])
    def main( args : Array[String] ) {
        val x = new XMLInputFormat()
        val job = new Job(new Configuration(), "")
        job setInputFormatClass classOf[XMLInputFormat]
    }
}
```

What's going on here?  Is there a fix for this that doesn't seem like so much of a hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug with scala 2.9.0 (which is what I was using).  When I upgraded to scala 2.9.1, the problem went away.